# Changes to navigationItem displayed with delay

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm facing a delay when changing properties of a `navigationItem` inside a `ViewController` which is embedded in a `NavigationController`.

Consider the example Master-Detail-App provided by XCode: It contains a `MasterViewController` with a segue to a `DetailViewController`. I'm now trying to customize the navigation bar inside the `viewDidLoad` method of the DetailViewController.

```swift
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //delay if the button (or any other property) is set here
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }
}
```

The changes to the navigation bar will be displayed but with a noticeable delay. However, if the changes to the navigation bar are made from within the `MasterViewController` everything works perfectly fine and smooth:

```swift
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

                //no delay if the button would instead be set here
                //navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
       }
    }
}
```

To me it seems not to be a **good practice** to modify items of the `navigationBar` from within the `MasterViewController`. Especially because 
items like the `title` and `buttons` heavily depend on the `DetailViewController`.

What is now the **most preferable way** to change the `navigationItem` without delay and with separation of concern in mind?

Comment: Try doing it in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` is already too late for navigation item changes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately placing the code in ```viewWillAppear``` will still lead to a noticeable delay.

Comment: Add the code where you're creating `editButtonItem`.

Comment: @PGDev there is no extra initializing code for the ```editButtonItem```, it is provided by the view controller. But the same delay would occure if you'd set the ```naviagtionItem.title = "my title"```

Answer (score -1):

Add `code` to `viewWillApear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewWillApear() {
        super.viewWillApear()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }
```